# Algebraic Data types in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, types, linear-algebra

I’m trying to make a set of functions and subs of basic algebraic operations like matrix product, vector product, finding the inverse of a matrix.

I have been using multidimensional arrays so far, and declaring them as variants, because for some reason, when you want a function to return an array value, by setting it equal to an array inside the function, it only works if they are both of type variant .

I want to declare a data type called *vector* which could be scalar, vector, matrix, or even something with more dimensionality, so when I declare a generic function like addition, I can say:

```
function addition (vect1 as vector, vect2 as vector) as vector
```

or maybe:

```
function addition (vect1() as vector, vect2() as vector) as vector()
```

and it works for every *vector* type (as long as vect1 and vect2 are the same size obviously).

I would like *vector*’s components to be addressed like arrays are e.g.

`vect1(2,3) and not vect1.row(2).column(3)`

Is it possible to create such data type in VBA? It's basically the data type you work with in mathlab or octave but I would like to create in VBA and to take values from MS Excel.

Comment: This question seems vague. VBA is object oriented. You can define classes and write functions which take certain classes as input/output. You could of course define a `vect` class. Whether or not you would be happy with the result, I couldn't say.

Comment: Apologies if I have mis-construed anything in the edit. You can hit the [edit]  option and rollback to prior version if required.

Comment: @JohnColeman thanks. it IS vague because i'm not quite sure how to do what I want. i'm really new in this and I wasn't familiar with class modules. I guess i'll try with that for a while and see if I can come up with a solution.